# Flatten array of objects of arrays JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to flatten an array of objects of arrays. For example, we might have something like so:

```
[{ numbers: [1, 2, 3] }, { numbers: [4, 5] }, { numbers: [6] }]
```

I would like to flatten it into:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I have a working solution doing something like this:

```js
const arr = [{ numbers: [1, 2, 3] }, { numbers: [4, 5] }, { numbers: [6] }];
const almostFlattened = arr.map((obj) => obj.numbers);
const flattened = [].concat.apply([], almostFlattened);
console.log(flattened);
```

Does anyone know of an easier or more performant solution here, preferably without the `almostFlattened` middle step?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try `Array.reduce()`, and flatten the numbers' arrays by concatenating the numbers with the accumulator:

```js
const arr = [{ numbers: [1, 2, 3] }, { numbers: [4, 5] }, { numbers: [6] }];

const result = arr.reduce((r, obj) => r.concat(obj.numbers), []);

console.log(result);
```

Another option is `Array.flatMap()` (not supported by IE/Edge):

```js
const arr = [{ numbers: [1, 2, 3] }, { numbers: [4, 5] }, { numbers: [6] }];

const result = arr.flatMap(obj => obj.numbers);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: you could also consolidate the push and return to `=> ( r.push(...obj.numbers), r )`

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use what you have, but inline? There's no need to declare a middle variable `almostFlattened` when you can put the `.map` call as part of the arguments to `.concat`:

```js
const arr = [{ numbers: [1, 2, 3] }, { numbers: [4, 5] }, { numbers: [6] }]
const result = [].concat(...arr.map(o => o.numbers));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Right, I just added the `almostFlattened` variable to explicitly highlight that middle step I am taking. My actual code is doing it inline.

Answer (score 1):

Use the spread syntax with `reduce`:

```js
const input = [{ numbers: [1, 2, 3] }, { numbers: [4, 5] }, { numbers: [6] }]
const output = input.reduce(((outputSoFar, { numbers }) => [...outputSoFar, ...numbers]), []);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

FlatMap is great

```
const data = [{ numbers: [1, 2, 3] }, { numbers: [4, 5] }, { numbers: [6] }]

data.flatMap(n => n.numbers)
```

If you want to flatten object with arrays:

```
Object.values({one: [1,2,3], two: [4,5,6]}).flat()
```

Answer (score 0):

I also figured I would throw this out there in case anyone is using something like lodash/underscore (did not know this function existed at the time I posted the question):

```js
const arr = [{ numbers: [1, 2, 3] }, { numbers: [4, 5] }, { numbers: [6] }];
const flattened = _.flatten(arr, 'numbers');
console.log(flattened);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@2.4.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For much more deeply nested array of arrays such as:
`[1, 2, 3, [4, [5, [6, [7]]]]]`

```
const flatten = (input, acc=[]) => {
    return input.reduce((_, current) => {
        if (Array.isArray(current)) return flatten(current, acc);  
        acc.push(current);
        return acc;
    }, []);
}
```

Usage:

```
console.log(flatten([1, 2, 3, [4, [5, [6, [7]]]]]));
```